# Turn on 'Show subsite in Quick Launch on Parent Page'

Tags: sub-site, quick-launch

I have recently set up a number of subsites but I have realised that when I did the initial set up I did not turn on the 'Show Subsite in Quick Launch on Parent Page' option.  I have searched and searched but I cannot find how to change this.

If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- You will need to first activate "**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**" feature in **Site collection feature**.
- Then activate "**SharePoint Server Publishing**" feature in **Site feature**.
- Then you will get "**Navigation**" link as shown below.

[image]

- Then go to Navigation link and check "**Show Subsite**" checkbox in **Current Navigation** section.

It will shows subsite under current navigation.